# Interactive matrix input in Python (analog to shinyMatrix in R Shiny)

Tags: python, r, matrix, shiny, interactive

In R shiny there is a package `shinyMatrix`, which enables a user to have an interactive matrix input for R shiny Apps. This means that you see an actual table where you can modify each value of a Matrix you want to input. (see: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/02/shinymatrix-matrix-input-for-shiny-apps/)

Is there a possibility to have something like this in Python as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is there a possibility to have something like this in Python as well?*

Yes, [`Dash`](https://dash.plotly.com/introduction) can provide interactive web data visulation thus is similar in purpose to `shiny`. DataTable widget provide table which should suffice if you are working with 2D matrices. In [`DataTable editable` feature docs](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/editable) you can find working example with data from such element updating graph.